# Trying to make a click animation repeatable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a bar that slides horizontally. If it's positioned left, it will slide right. If it's positioned right, it will slide left. Eventually this will contain multiple bars side by side that will slide out of the way to reveal different images.

right now it would work fine except i can't seem to figure out how to get it to fire more than once. I'm not a javascript guy by any stretch of the imagination, so just a little push in the right direction would be appreciated.

Thanks
Luke

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
    var x=1;
    $(document).ready(function(){
      if( x==1 )
      {
        x=2;
        $("#block").click(function()
         {
          $("#block").animate({right:'20px'});
         });
        return;
      }

      if( x==2 )
      {
        x=1;
        $("#block").click(function()
         {
          $("#block").animate({left:'20px'});
         });
        return;
      }


    });
    </script>
    </head>



    <body>

    <p> This block should slide right if it's positioned left, and slide left if it's positioned right. It should repeat this behavior indefinitely. Right now it's being very naughty indeed!</p>

    <div id=block style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:16px;position:absolute;">
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bind the event out the if statment and put the condition in side event.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/tVEuu/1/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var x=1;           
    $("#block").click(function()
    {
       if( x==1 )
       {
           x=2;
           $("#block").animate({right:'20px'});
       }
       else
       {
           x=1;
           $("#block").animate({left:'20px'});
       }
     });
 });
```

To keep the rule cycle you may need to change the code like given below

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/tVEuu/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var x = 1;
    $("#block").click(function() {
        if (x == 1) {
            x = 2;
            $("#block").animate({
                right:  '20px',
                 left: '0px'
            });
        }
        else {
            x = 1;
            $("#block").animate({
                left: '20px',
                 right:  '0px'
            });
        }
    });
});​
```

Comment: After two clicks, the element gets both a `right` and `left` CSS rule, and it will not update anymore.

Comment: The demo shows it animating the left position between 0 and 20, and never right: 20

Comment: Thanks, this did it. I also decided to position everything off left to completely remove that issue. Thanks again

Comment: also jsfiddle is a great tool that i wasn't aware of, i'll use it a lot now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot easily animate `left` and `right`, because jQuery doesn't know the exact end position when you change `left: 0` to `right: 0`. What you can do is calculating this yourself and using `left` only. Some other things are:

- Use a boolean to flip instead of a number
- Don't decide what event handler to bind, but decide what should happen when the handler is called
- Use `$(this)` for the current element

http://jsfiddle.net/HZRWJ/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var isLeft = true;
    $("#block").click(function() {
        var fullWidth = $(document).width();
        var elemWidth = $(this).width();
        if(isLeft) {
            $(this).animate({ left: fullWidth - elemWidth });
        } else {
            $(this).animate({ left: 0 });
        }
        isLeft = !isLeft;
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this do something similar to what you wanted?

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/RxCHQ/)

```
$("#block").data('position', 'left');
$("#block").click(function() {
    var elem = $(this);
    resetElementPosition(elem);
    switch (elem.data('position')) {
        case 'left': elem.animate({ right: '20px' }); elem.data('position', 'right'); break;
        case 'right': elem.animate({ left: '20px' }); elem.data('position', 'left'); break;
        }
});

function resetElementPosition(element)
{
    element.css({ 'left' : 'auto', 'right' : 'auto' });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to have multiple bars it might be easier to store values in a jQuery object.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("#block").each( function( ) {

       // associate data with each element. At the moment there should 
       // only be one but if this is implemented as a class there may
       // be more
       $(this).data("x", 0);

   });

   $("#block").click( function( ) {

       // 0 will push it to the right as 0 => false
       if( $(this).data("x") ) { 

           $(this).data("x", 0 );

           // removing the css property allows you to use left & right
           $(this).css("right","").animate({left:'20px'});

       } else {

           $(this).data("x", 1 );

           $(this).css("left","").animate({right:'20px'});

       }
     });
   });
```

Demo [here](http://jsbin.com/iqohon/1/edit)